# WordPress Broken Images

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url

I don't know what can cause this problem, but my WordPress web-site after migrating to new server is not showing me images. It is maybe something in `.htaccess` file, rewrite rule or something. Any directions please?

Please click [here](http://www.odgajivacnicasvabic.com/kavezi/) to see my page.
`.htaccess` from `public_html` directory:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

`.htaccess` file from wp-content/uploads:

```
# BEGIN alti-watermark Plugin
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*(-([1-3][\d]{1,2}|[\d]{1,2})x300|-300x([1-3][\d]{1,2}|[\d]{1,2})|-([1-1][\d]{1,3}|[\d]{1,3})x1024|-1024x([1-1][\d]{1,3}|[\d]{1,3})|-940x446)\.jpg|.*(?<!-\dx\d)(?<!-\d\dx\d)(?<!-\dx\d\d)(?<!-\d\dx\d\d)(?<!-\d\d\dx\d\d)(?<!-\d\dx\d\d\d)(?<!-\d\d\dx\d\d\d)(?<!-\d\d\d\dx\d\d\d)(?<!-\d\d\d\dx\d\d)(?<!-\d\d\dx\d\d\d\d)(?<!-\d\d\d\dx\d\d\d\d)(?<!-\d\d\d\dx\d\d\d)(?<!-\d\d\d\dx\d\d)(?<!-\d\d\d\d\dx\d\d\d\d\d)\.jpg){1}((\?|\&)([^\.\?\ ]+))*$ ../plugins/alti-watermark/public/views/alti-watermark-public-bridge.php?imageRequested=$1 [PT]
</ifModule>
# [date=2016-12-27 18:06.57] [php=5.4.45] [width=300x300|1024x1024|940x446|fullsize] [plugin_name=alti-watermark] [version=0.3]
# END alti-watermark Plugin
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: All of your resources are returning `400`s, check your server logs for more details. Voting to close as too broad. If you think it might be your .htaccess... Then why did you not post it?

Comment: @MattClark Updated. Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually that's because file paths are saved as absolute paths in the database.

In this case you either need to get some plugin that changes all those filepaths for you (see https://wordpress.org/plugins/search/migration/ for resources) or export your database as a mysql file, open it in an editor and do a search/replace to replace all old filepath instances with the new one, and then import that again in your database.